# Show Comma seperated values one by one in crystal report?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to take the a comma seperated values in CR and return it with column of fields . Instead of..

```
Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name 4.
```

it would be

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace function is: `Replace (inputString, findString, replaceString)`

```
Replace ("Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name 4", ",", ChrW (10))
```

Comment: I updated your code and initally Name 1 was alone coming.When i set cangrow to the field it is working as intended..